# Deploy Unity3d HTML5/WebGL build as a node.js app to Heroku/HCP/OpenShift

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to deploy a HTML5 Unity3d application to Heroku or any other hosting platform?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes.

Comment: how come? I couldn't find any tutorial..

Comment: have you done the webgl export yet?